# Why are there parentheses around scalar when assigning the return value of regex match in this Perl snippet?

Tags: perl

I wrote the following regex in order to get the digits from a string:

```
my ($digits) = ($str =~ /(\d+)/);
```

It works as expected but I was wondering why I need to use parentheses around `$digits`? Why doesn't it work without the parenthesis? I tried to find some information about it on the web but didn't find any.

Why can I use it like this:

```
my $digits = ($str =~ /(\d+)/);
```

Can I make the changes on the `$str`? something like this: `$str =~ /(\d+)/;`?

Comment: Do you know about scalar vs list context in Perl?

Comment: You need parenthesis to create so-called list context, as noted by @melpomene ,see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) and [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) for more information.

Comment: https://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl

Comment: See [Context in `perldoc perldata`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context). This documentation is installed along with `perl`, there is no need to search the intarwebs. See also, `$ perldoc perltoc`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two assignment operators denoted by `=`:

- The scalar assignment operator.
- The list assignment operator.

Perl decides which one to use based on whether the left-hand side (LHS) of the assignment is some kind of aggregate or not. The following are considered to be aggregates, which result in the use of the list assignment operator:

- `(...)` (any expression in parentheses)
- `@array`
- `@array[...]`
- `%hash`
- `@hash{...}`
- Any of the above preceded by `my`, `our` or `local`

There are two differences between the operators.

The first is the context in which its operands are evaluated.

- The scalar assignment evaluates both of its operands in scalar context.
- The list assignment evaluates both of its operands in list context.

The second difference is what they return.

- The scalar assignment evaluates to the LHS as an lvalue.
- The list assignment in scalar context evaluates to the number of scalars returned by the RHS.
- The list assignment in list context evaluates to the scalars returned by the LHS as lvalues.

Examples are found [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129).

The first difference is the one that matters in your case.

- `my $digits = $str =~ /(\d+)/;` uses the scalar assignment operator, which evaluates `$str =~ /(\d+)/` and thus `/(\d+)/` in scalar context. In scalar context, `/(\d+)/` and thus `$str =~ /(\d+)/` evaluates to whether the match was successful or not.
- `my ($digits) = $str =~ /(\d+)/;` uses the list assignment operator, which evaluates `$str =~ /(\d+)/` and thus `/(\d+)/` in list context. In list context, `/(\d+)/` and thus `$str =~ /(\d+)/` evaluates to the strings captured by the match.

Comment: @ysth Ok, I agree. I will delete my previous comments. But the answer is still not clear to me. For example: *"The list assignment evaluates both of its operands in list context"* and later *"The list assignment in scalar context evaluates to the..."* First it says that list assignment evaluates both its operands in list context, and later it talks about list assignment in scalar context. I cannot make sense out of it yet.

Comment: @HåkonHægland the context in which the assignment is evaluated is not necessarily the same as the context in which it evaluates its operands. Example of a list assignment in scalar context: `while ( my ($k,$v) = each (%h) ) { ... }` Another: `my $count = () = f();`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It makes sense now.